# Loop com dataframes em regressão logística ordenada

Tags: loop, r, dataframe, regressão

Preciso estimar uma regressão logística ordenada na qual a base esta dividida em 417 dataframes dando um total de 33,7 GB. Juntar todos os subsets em um único dataframe tornaria a opção lenta. Por isso pensei em fazer as estimações em pedaços da seguinte forma (uso o exemplo abaixo que reproduz a mesma lógica do meu problema):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)

#Criando dataframe 1
party <- factor(rep(c("Rep","Dem"), c(407, 428)), 
                levels=c("Rep","Dem"))  
rpi <- c(30, 46, 148, 84, 99) # cell counts
dpi <- c(80, 81, 171, 41, 55) # cell counts
ideology <- c("Very Liberal","Slightly Liberal","Moderate","Slightly Conservative","Very Conservative")
pol.ideology <- factor(c(rep(ideology, rpi), 
                         rep(ideology, dpi)), levels = ideology)
data1 <- data.frame(party,pol.ideology)

#Criando dataframe 2
party <- factor(rep(c("Rep","Dem"), c(410, 430)), 
                levels=c("Rep","Dem"))  
rpi2 <- c(26, 50, 140, 95, 99) # cell counts
dpi2 <- c(75, 86, 141, 61, 67) # cell counts
ideology2 <- c("Very Liberal","Slightly Liberal","Moderate","Slightly Conservative","Very Conservative")
pol.ideology <- factor(c(rep(ideology2, rpi2), 
                         rep(ideology2, dpi2)), levels = ideology2)
data2 <- data.frame(party,pol.ideology)

nrow(data1)
nrow(data2)

## Juntando dataframes "manualmente"
dat <- bind_rows(data1,data2)

table(dat)
nrow(dat)

# fit proportional odds model

pom <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data=dat)
summary(pom)
```

Daí tenho o seguinte output:

```
Call:
polr(formula = pol.ideology ~ party, data = dat)

Coefficients:
           Value Std. Error t value
partyDem -0.8911    0.09016  -9.884

Intercepts:
                                        Value    Std. Error t value 
Very Liberal|Slightly Liberal            -2.4621   0.0929   -26.4893
Slightly Liberal|Moderate                -1.4215   0.0755   -18.8239
Moderate|Slightly Conservative            0.1641   0.0659     2.4905
Slightly Conservative|Very Conservative   1.0570   0.0728    14.5272

Residual Deviance: 5042.654 
AIC: 5052.654
```

Como são 417 de arquivos pensei em criar um loop para não ter que juntar manualmente os dataframes:

```
## LOOP
data = ls(pattern="data")
for(i in 1:length(ls(pattern="data"))){
  pom <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, data=i)  
}
summary(pom)
```

Usando o loop tenho o seguinte output:

```
Re-fitting to get Hessian

Call:
polr(formula = pol.ideology ~ party, data = i)

Coefficients:
           Value Std. Error t value
partyDem -0.8115     0.1262  -6.433

Intercepts:
                                        Value    Std. Error t value 
Very Liberal|Slightly Liberal            -2.4608   0.1315   -18.7135
Slightly Liberal|Moderate                -1.3726   0.1049   -13.0858
Moderate|Slightly Conservative            0.0947   0.0923     1.0267
Slightly Conservative|Very Conservative   1.0455   0.1020    10.2527

Residual Deviance: 2559.949 
AIC: 2569.949
```

*Observo que os valores dos coeficientes e os valores t são diferentes entre o primeiro (estimado juntando manualmente os dataframes e o segundo modelo (estimado usando loop entre os dataframes), não deveria ser pois se trata dos mesmos dados*. **Em resumo, desejo estimar uma única regressão logística com esses dois data.frames. Minha dúvida é: o loop que construí deveria considerar todos os dataframes, mas no momento só está considerando o último dataframe. O que estou fazendo de errado na construção do loop? Qual seria a solução?**

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi o for direito. Porque pelo que entendi você está estimando o modelo uma vez para cada tabela nele, mas assim o valor  de pom vai ser apenas referente a última tabela que passou no for e não a todas juntas.

Comment: Porquê carregar o pacote `tidyverse`? Só o pacote `dplyr` chega bem.

Comment: Jorge Mendes: A minha ideia é que o modelo faça a estimação usando toda as tabelas. Por isso que usei `ls(pattern="data")` para utilizar todos os objetos com nome data (no caso, os dataframes data1 e data2). Como poderia fazer p utilizar todas as tabelas? Pelo que vi, realmente só está sendo feita a estimação com data2.

Comment: Rui Barradas: Verdade, o `dplyr` resolve. Usei o `tidyverse` porque repliquei de outro código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há dois problemas com seu *loop*:

2. Está fazendo uma regressão para cada um dos *data.frames*, não para os dados dos dois juntos.
3. A cada volta do loop o conteúdo do objeto `pom` é reescrito, ou seja, no final tem apenas o resultado da regressão para `data2`.

Se quer uma regressão para todos os dados, precisa uni-los primeiro. A melhor opção para isso é aplicar read* à uma string com os nomes dos arquivos e uni-los em uma chamada:

```
# Salvando seus dados de exemplo em arquivos:
write.csv(data1, 'dados1.csv')
write.csv(data2, 'dados2.csv')

lista_de_arquivos <- list.files(pattern = ".csv$")

complete_data <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lista_de_arquivos, read.csv))
```

Ou, se está usando tidyverse:

```
complete_data <- lista_de_arquivos %>% map_df(~read.csv(.))
```

Com os dados unidos, realiza uma única regressão:

```
pom <- polr(pol.ideology ~ party, complete_data)
```

O problema no seu caso é o grande volume de dados. Infelizmente, não é possível fazer a regressão em porções e depois unir os resultados para ter a resposta de uma regressão para todos os dados. Pode otimizar a leitura dos dados, usando funções mais rápidas (como read_csv do tidyverse, ou fread do data.table), carregando apenas as colunas que precisa e codificando strings de texto como integrais, mas pode não ser suficiente. Nesse caso, entra em Big Data, o que foge do escopo de uma resposta no SO.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição! Vou tentar unir os data frames e otimizar. Estive tentando com o read.csv.ffdf() e percebi que otimiza muito o amanho do arquivo, mas vou comparar tb com o read_csv do tidyverse, ou fread do data.table). Caso não consiga, irei tentar armazenar os data frames num servidor postgreSQL e fazer conexão ODBC com o R.